# Show random picture with Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code which shows randomly a URL to a picture.
I want to add the random shown URL to the part where the picture is created.

How can I extract the URL from JavaScript and use it in html? Test.jpg should be replaced with the random generated URL.

```js
var myimages = [{
  image: "https://cdn.prod.www.manager-magazin.de/images/ca3dd5d1-0001-0004-0000-000000088705_w920_r1.778_fpx42.51_fpy49.99.jpg",
  probability: 0.1
}, {
  image: "https://p6.focus.de/img/fotos/id_40323993/porsche-cayman-heck.jpg?im=Crop%3D%280%2C20%2C1600%2C800%29%3BResize%3D%28800%2C400%29&impolicy=perceptual&quality=medium&hash=69314e722c29162f49edafd9b16362ceb1a704219e2a128272824e5d8d585019",
  probability: 0.1
}, {
  image: "https://i.auto-bild.de/ir_img/1/7/6/3/5/7/9/Alle-Auto-Neuheiten-2019-1200x800-bbcf8a2e46bd3f1f.jpg",
  probability: 0.25
}, {
  image: "https://cache.pressmailing.net/thumbnail/story_hires/64940fdd-8ec9-4854-98f9-e7f7467414b7/image.jpg",
  probability: 0.55
}];

function getImage() {
  var rand = Math.random();
  var probabilitiy_sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myimages.length; i++) {
    probabilitiy_sum += myimages[i].probability;
    if (rand <= probabilitiy_sum) {
      return myimages[i].image;
    }
  }
  return myimages[myimages.length].image;
}

// Just for testing:
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML += getImage() + "<br />";
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Image</h2>
<img src="test.jpg" width="460" height="345">
<div id="textbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `src` of an image tag, similar to how you're currently setting the innerHTML of a div:

```js
var myimages = [{
  image: "https://cdn.prod.www.manager-magazin.de/images/ca3dd5d1-0001-0004-0000-000000088705_w920_r1.778_fpx42.51_fpy49.99.jpg",
  probability: 0.1
}, {
  image: "https://p6.focus.de/img/fotos/id_40323993/porsche-cayman-heck.jpg?im=Crop%3D%280%2C20%2C1600%2C800%29%3BResize%3D%28800%2C400%29&impolicy=perceptual&quality=medium&hash=69314e722c29162f49edafd9b16362ceb1a704219e2a128272824e5d8d585019",
  probability: 0.1
}, {
  image: "https://i.auto-bild.de/ir_img/1/7/6/3/5/7/9/Alle-Auto-Neuheiten-2019-1200x800-bbcf8a2e46bd3f1f.jpg",
  probability: 0.25
}, {
  image: "https://cache.pressmailing.net/thumbnail/story_hires/64940fdd-8ec9-4854-98f9-e7f7467414b7/image.jpg",
  probability: 0.55
}];

function getImage() {
  var rand = Math.random();
  var probabilitiy_sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myimages.length; i++) {
    probabilitiy_sum += myimages[i].probability;
    if (rand <= probabilitiy_sum) {
      return myimages[i].image;
    }
  }
  return myimages[myimages.length].image;
}

// Just for testing:
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML += getImage() + "<br />";
  document.getElementById("image").src = getImage() // <-- here
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="test.jpg" width="460" height="345">

<div id="textbox"></div>
```

Comment: Great this works. It shows the right picture but also the url. How can I hide the url? Deleting return myimages[myimages.length].image; does not work.

Comment: It's showing the URL because I left in your code that shows the URL.  If you don't want that, remove the line that sets the innerHTML of `#textbox`. The only code change I made in this answer was to add the line that demonstrates how to set the `src` of an image.